# getting the child text from a div in a .each loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

this is just a couple of lines of code that i have in my page.
I am using the jquery ui drag and drop. These are two of the items of many

when the saved button is press i need to get all the IDs and the text in the group_name div

This function gets the ID ok but i can not figure out how to get the $('group_name').text() from the current LI in the each loop.

```
   function saveChanges(){
        $("li.ui-state-default").each(function() {
            var $divitem = $( this );
            console.log($divitem.attr('id'));
        });
    }
```

this is the html snippet

```
<li id="5" class="ui-state-default">
<div class="group_name">Classes</div>
<div class="group_footer">
      <a title="Delete this group" class="mytrash-icon" href="#">
         <img border="0" src="trash.png" class="mytrash-img"></a>
      <a title="Manage Subfolders" class="subfolder" href="#">   
         <img border="0" src="Folder-Icon.png"></a>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="6" class="ui-state-default">
<div class="group_name">Coaching</div>
<div class="group_footer">
        <a title="Delete this group" class="mytrash-icon" href="#">
          <img border="0" src="trash.png" class="mytrash-img"></a>
        <a title="Manage Subfolders" class="subfolder" href="#">
          <img border="0" src="Folder-Icon.png"></a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: inside the loop add `$(this).find('.group_name').text()`. Maybe, add a new attribute `data-groupname="The_Text"` and then you get it like this `$divitem.data('groupname')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use .find()

```
$("li.ui-state-default").each(function() {
    var $divitem = $(this);
    console.log($divitem.find(".group_name").text());
});​
```

Another would be to use .children()

```
$("li.ui-state-default").each(function() {
    var $divitem = $(this);
    console.log($divitem.children(".group_name").text());
});​
```

#### But the one I like is neither

```
$("li.ui-state-default").each(function() {
    var $divitem = $(this);
    console.log($(".group_name", $divitem).text());
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

```
$divitem.find(".group_name").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li.ui-state-default").each(function() {
    var $divitem = $(this);
    console.log($divitem.find(".group_name").text());
});​
```